# Does $\mathbb R \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \mathfrak{aff}(1,\mathbb R) \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \mathbb R$ Lie algebra extension exist?

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, lie-algebra-cohomology, central-extensions

I think I have an example for a $\mathbb R \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \mathfrak{aff}(1,\mathbb R) \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \mathbb R$ Lie algebra extension.
$$\iota:\mathbb R\to \mathfrak{aff}(1,\mathbb R): x\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}0 & x\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ is an embedding of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathfrak{aff}(1,\mathbb R)$ as an ideal, and the map
$$\pi:\mathfrak{aff}(1,\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R: \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\mapsto a$$
is a surjective projection onto $\mathbb R$ having kernel $\iota(\mathbb R)$, so with these functions, the sequence in question is exact, hence it is a Lie algebra extension. But I think such an extension should not exist because $H^2(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)=0$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $H^2$ classifies central extensions; this extension isn't central.

Comment: Oh, really, $\left[\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & x\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\right]=\begin{pmatrix}0 & ax\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Thank you!