# Proof of $H^2(\mathfrak g_1,\mathfrak g_1)=0$

Tags: lie-algebras, homology-cohomology, lie-algebra-cohomology, central-extensions

I want to prove $H^2(\mathfrak g_1,\mathfrak g_1)=0$ where $\mathfrak g_1=\mathbb R$, the $1$-dimensional (abelian) Lie algebra.

I think I need to show two things:

1. All central extensions $\mathbb R \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow}
       \mathbb R^2 \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow} \mathbb R$ are
   equivalent to each other.
2. There isn't any $\mathbb R \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \mathfrak{aff}(1,\mathbb R) \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow}\mathbb R$ central extension.

Originally, I thought that there isn't $\mathbb R \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \mathfrak{aff}(1,\mathbb R) \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow}\mathbb R$ extension at all, but it [isn't true](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4620051/63290). I see now that the extension I found isn't central, but I have to prove that none of the  $\mathbb R \overset{\iota}{\hookrightarrow} \mathfrak{aff}(1,\mathbb R) \overset{\pi}{\twoheadrightarrow}\mathbb R$ extensions are central. But I have no idea how to prove this and point 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the center of the affine Lie algebra $L={\rm aff}(n,\Bbb R)$ is zero, since this algebra is *complete*, i.e., we have
$$
0=H^0(L,L)=Z(L),\; H^1(L,L)={\rm Out}(L)=0.
$$
So there cannot be an injective map from $\Bbb R$ to the center of $L$.
It is well known that complete Lie algebras $L$ with solvable radical ${\rm rad}(L)$ being abelian satisfy
$$
H^n(L,L)=0, \; \forall \; n\ge 0.
$$
For a reference see [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_75_sympa.pdf). In particular, $H^2(L,L)=0$, so that $L$ is "rigid".

However, you have asked about the second adjoint cohomology for a $1$-dimensional Lie algebra, i.e.,  $\mathfrak{g}_1$ is not ${\rm aff}(1,\Bbb R)$, but  $\Bbb R$. There we have $H^2(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)=0$, because in general $H^n(L,M)=0$ for $n>\dim (L)$.

Comment: Thanks. And what about point 1?

Comment: Point 1 follows from $H^2(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)=0$, so there is only the trivial equivalence class of central extensions of $\Bbb R$ by $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Complete Lie algebras are new for me and I couldn't find anything about them in a textbook or Wikipedia. However I found a definition [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1998-126-01/S0002-9939-98-03911-2/S0002-9939-98-03911-2.pdf) as "A Lie algebra L is called a complete Lie algebra if its centre C(L) is zero and
its derivations are all inner", while ChatGpt told that A Lie algebra is said to be "complete" when it is isomorphic to its own complexification." Could you show a resource that clarifies this?

Comment: And could you please add a reference for the statement $H^n(L,M)=0$ for $n>\dim (L)$?

Comment: The standard complex for Lie algebra cohomology has the space of cochains $C^k(L,M)={\rm Hom}_K(\Lambda^k(L),M)$, where the exterior algebra $\Lambda^k(L)$ has the dimension $\binom{n}{k}$, for $n=\dim (L)$. This is zero for $k>n$. This can be found in any reference listed in [wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology). For complete Lie algebras you have the references given in the paper you have linked. The word "complete" also depends on the exact context, e.g., for complete metric spaces.